# Should I use "continue to be" or "continue being"?

Tags: grammar

In this sentence, I cannot make up my mind...

Which one is correct? Or which one is better, in case both are correct.

> This feature allows setting whether the Application Bar will **continue
>   to be** visible when the end-user scrolls down the content

or

> This feature allows setting whether the Application Bar will **continue
>   being** visible when the end-user scrolls down the content

Comment: Little difference.  I prefer the first, but couldn't say why!

Comment: Marcos, I find Google Book Ngram viewer of great help to get an idea of whether a particular word combination (five words max) is idiomatic or not. Have a look: [*continue to be* is 80-100 times more frequent than *continue being*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=continue+to+be%2Ccontinue+being&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontinue%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinue%20being%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score -1):

I believe in this application one would rather say "continue being". Both are correct, however "continue being" allows for less of a pause in the sentence tempo when read. Being can be defined as in existence and the Application Bar is an instance that can be called into existence, thereby displayed on screen, being is the appropriate noun to use.

One might suggest, if you are looking at properly wording the sentence, add "or not" after "whether" so the sentence would be as follows: This feature allows setting whether or not the Application Bar will continue being visible when the end-user scrolls down the content.